# Should I receive an error in my console when bootstrap Glyphicons doesn't show up?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, modx, glyphicons

Working on a MODx / Bootstrap site, I can't make glyphicons show up on the site, also some parts of navbar design doesn't show up (but I'm sure css is loading, and hence, I think it's glyphicons that are the problem.

The problem is, I have no error on my console at all; no missing file warning, nothing. How should I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Without seeing any code it's hard to suggest anything...

Answer (score 0):

they show up fine - I don't see anywhere that you have assigned the glyphicon classes e.g. class="glyphicon glyphicon-whatever"

what is not showing up in the menu?

Comment: yes, i checked that site, i not see any glyph icons called, if add them in the element inspector, they show up.What he expect?

Comment: Yes, at this stage there are no glyph icons in the code, but please look at the navbar, which is a standard bootstrap one with the bottstrap defualt theme; you see the round gray border around it is missing, also, if you resize the window to smaller sizes, the "three vertical lines" mobile menu icon doesn't appear.

Comment: doesn't look stock, looks like you have reordered the html elements in it.. I don't see any custom CSS other than the included theme. Looks like your navbar header is outside the navbar. probably why it doesn't 'show up' .  It's a good idea to take a look at the bootstrap CSS & use an inspector to learn how the navbar actually works [and how it's elements inherit styles] before trying to modify it. 

You modded the nav to get it to align right beside the logo? Drop your logo in a responsive column say then the whole [stock] navbar in a 2nd column  OR replace your navbar-brand with the logo...

Comment: @SeanKimball Thanks Sean! I didn't touched the navbar code, it's from bootstrap website. However I might made a mistake somewhere. I will re-check.

Comment: @SeanKimball Solved! It was the phpTidy plugin inside my ModX CMS.